# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql

**DB Schema**

[image]

Using query:

```
SELECT
    fa.nombre,
    COUNT(pro.nombre)
FROM
    fabricante AS fa
    LEFT JOIN producto AS pro ON fa.id = pro.id_fabricante
GROUP BY
    fa.nombre
HAVING
    pro.precio >= 180;
```

Error message:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'pro.precio' in 'having clause'

Dont know whats wrong with the query. Please help

Comment: Conceptually, the `GROUP BY` step of a query results in a new table and breaks any references to tables in the `FROM` step (unless they're used as grouping-keys), and the `HAVING` step is after `GROUP BY`, so you cannot reference `pro.precio` in the `HAVING` step.

Comment: There is a lot of different `pro.precio` values which matches the same `fa.nombre`. GROUP BY collapses all rows with the same `fa.nombre` to one row. Server does not know what value from all possible ones it must use for `pro.precio`, so this column is defined as non-available. ...

Comment: ... If you need to access the value from this column then you must define what one from all ones must be used. You may either include this column into GROUP BY expression (it is safe when all rows with the same `fa.nombre` contains the same `pro.precio` value) or use needed aggregate function (for example, use not immediate column but `MIN(pro.precio)`).